# overflow only for particular divs not working

Tags: css, height, overflow

I am trying to make a Cms, with 100% height for the container, and overall overflow hidden, overflow only for 'side nav' and 'work area', auto height for the same, Please help, please look at the attached picture[image]

```
// HTML and CSS BELOW
    <?php
    echo '<!DOCTYPE html>';
    echo '<html>';
    echo '<head>';
    echo '</head>';
    echo '<body>';
    echo '<div id = "main_container">';
    echo '<div id = "top_1">';
    echo '<div id = "header_1">';
    echo '<div id = "header_1_a">';
    echo "logo";
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div id = "header_1_b">';
    echo "name";
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div id = "header_2">';
    echo '<div id = "header_2_a">';
    echo "person name";
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div id = "header_2_b">';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div id = "header_3">';
    echo '<div id = "header_3_a">';
    echo "address";
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div id = "header_3_b">';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div id = "content_1">';
    echo '<div id = "content_1_a" >';
    echo '<div id = "side_nav_1" >';
    echo '<div id = "side_nav_1_a" >';
    echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div id = "work_area_1">';
    echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  echo 'hello world <br />';  
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div id = "footer_1">';
    echo '<div id = "footer_1_a">';
    echo '<div id = "copyr_1_a">';
    echo "HELLO";
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div id = "copyr_1_b">';
    echo "WORLD";
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    ?>


    body,html {
        margin : 0;
        padding : 0;
        overflow : hidden;
    }
    #main_container{
        background : orange;
        width : 100%;
        height : 100%;
        position : absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
    }
    #top_1{
        display : table;
        width : 100%;
        height : auto;
    }
    #header_1{
        background : #FFA500;
        display : table-row;
    }
    #header_1 #header_1_a{
        display : table-cell;
    }
    #header_1 #header_1_b{
        display : table-cell;
    }
    #header_2{
        background : #55595B;
        display : table-row;
        color : white;
    }
    #header_2 #header_2_a{
        display : table-cell;
    }
    #header_2 #header_2_b{
        display : table-cell;
    }
    #header_3{
        background : #F1F1F1;
        display : table-row;
        color : white;
    }
    #header_3 #header_3_a{
        display : table-cell;
    }
    #header_3 #header_3_b{
        display : table-cell;
    }
    #content_1{
        display : table;
        width : 100%;
    }
    #content_1_a{
        display : table-row;
        background : gray;
        width : 100%; 
    }
    #side_nav_1{
        display : table-cell;
        background : gray;
        width : 20;
    }
    #side_nav_1_a{
        height : auto;
        overflow : auto;
    }
    #work_area_1{
        display :table-cell;
        background : white;
        width : auto;
    }
    #work_area_1_a{
        height : auto;
        overflow : auto;
    }
    #footer_1{
        background : red;
        display : table;
        width : 100%;
        height : auto;
    }
    #footer_1_a{
        display : table-row;
        background : red;
    }
    #copyr_1_a{
        display : table-cell;
        background : red;
    }
    #copyr_1_b{
        display : table-cell;
        background : red;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Holà,

Why you use echo for all the HTML ??
Use class rather id, if you have lot of article, or user in back-off you don't id like "user_1, user_2, user_3" etc. and think about nomenclature (look css). Tips : you have 100vh (viewport height) instead of 100%.

I add Reset CSS, jQuery for check height of header & footer and add padding in content and i use while for display "Hello world".

It's really important to make a good base if you want to make a CMS, think 6 month later, if you are 2 ou more to develop code !

HTML / PHP :

```
<div id="main_container">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="header-logo" class="clearfix">
            <div class="header-logo-img">Logo</div>
            <div class="header-logo-name">Name</div>
        </div>
        <div class="header-person" class="clearfix">
            <div class="header-person-name">Person name</div>
            <div class="header-person-info"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="header-info" class="clearfix">
            <div class="header-info-adress">Address</div>
            <div class="header-info-phone"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="content-side-nav">
            <?php $i = 1;
            while($i <= 20) {
                echo '<p>hello world</p>';
                $i++;
            } ?> 
        </div>
        <div class="content-work">
            <?php $i2 = 1;
            while($i2 <= 200) {
                echo '<p>hello world</p>';
                $i2++;
            } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="footer-copyright">HELLO</div>
        <div class="footer-copyright">WORLD</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
} 
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
.clearfix {
    zoom: 1; /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
}
#main_container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: orange;
}
.header {
    position: fixed; /* or Absolute */
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
}
.header-logo, .header-person, .header-info {
    display: block;
    background: #FFA500;
    color: white;
}
.header-logo-img, .header-logo-name, .header-person-name, .header-person-info, .header-info-adress, .header-info-phone {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
.header-personn { background: #55595B; }
.header-info { background: #F1F1F1; }
.content {
    position: relative;
    padding: 48px 0 32px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.content-side-nav {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
    background: gray;
}
.content-work {
    float: left;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
    background: white;
}
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
}
.footer-copyright {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    background: red;
}
```

JS :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var headerH = $(".header").height(),
        footerH = $(".footer").height();
    $(".content").css({
        "padding-top": headerH,
        "padding-bottom": footerH,
    });
});
```

I hope that will help you.